# Is there a way to change default Modifiers' options?

Tags: scripting, modifiers, interface

Is there a way to change the default Modifiers' options? For example, Boolean options.

Let me explain: I work with high-poly models for 3D printing. And each time I forget to turn off preview option I have to wait for 1-5 minutes of calculating while risking Blender to crash. If I accidently choose e.g. Bevel instead of Boolean - the same. With this issue modelling becomes a real pain feeling like minesweeping. One wrong move - and you either waste 5 minutes or all loose unsaved progress. Or 5 minutes AND loss of progress.

I'm so done by this problem I'm even ready to bother myself with finding and editing internal Blender's scripts =) Or am I being stupid and there's a button that does this?

Also, this would save a lot of time because it'd save a ton of unnecessary clicking.

Thanks!

Comment: P.S. I've seen the answer "no way, because these scripts are in hidden the Blender's source", but it's dated back to 2015.

Comment: It is still true today, unless you are willing to dive into the source code, you can't. I hope there will be an option for it some day.

Comment: what i do is make a single vertex mesh and add what modifier i need then join second mesh to it. idk if there is a real solution for this and even i understood what you lookin for

Comment: If you're able to script, you could write your own modifier creating add-on. All the settings for bool ops and bevel and all modifiers are available via Python API (I think all, I personally haven't checked them all)

Comment: Another option would be to go the other way, _ie_ could look at ways to ensure preview mode is enabled every time you are over the modifier properties.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the info! Quite sad info tho =)